# JSON to excel conversion

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am converting JSON data to an excel file format. So far I have been able to create a file with the data.
I am looking forward to add a custom message to be displayed (image below) in the first row and thereafter data should be displayed in the file with column headers.

I have taken reference from this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-data-to-excel)

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

---

**New Issue**

[image]

`Missing headers firstName, lastName, email, phone`

Comment: what library are you using to create the file?

Comment: from what I can see you need to 1- add a row 2- merge its cells 3- set the value of the first cell to your desired message/content 4- set its format to fit your need.

Comment: @MaherFattouh, I guess it's `XLSX` library. I have tried searching for probable solution to it though, couldn't find one.

Comment: Sample example: https://medium.com/codeptivesolutions/working-with-excel-of-json-data-in-vuejs-using-xlsx-and-bootstrap-vue-9f40fc377d3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched about this a lot and finally I could come up with a solution to this.

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: Array<object>, excelFileName: string): void {
var worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([
  [`${excelFileName}`]]); // message to display
worksheet['!merges'] = [{ s: { r: 0, c: 0 }, e: { r: 0, c: 3 } }]; //for merging columns. s : start, e: end, c: column, r: row
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(worksheet, json, { origin: "A2" }); //origin for json data
const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
for (var C = range.s.r; C <= range.e.r; ++C) {
  var address = XLSX.utils.encode_col(C) + "1"; 
  if (!worksheet[address]) continue;
  worksheet[address].v = worksheet[address].v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + worksheet[address].v.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume when you say JSON, you mean a Javascript object that have been parsed from a JSON file.
in my example it's `myObject`.

1. We create a worksheet using `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myObject);`
2. We add a row to the start of the worksheet using: `XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(myWorkSheet, [["Your Mesage Goes Here"]], { origin: 0 });`
   this will insert an aoa (array of arrays) to a new row at the position defined by `origin`.

   - `{ origin: 0 }` means first row
   - `{ origin: 1 }` means 2nd row
   - `{ origin: -1 }` means last row

in our case we add just one cell (A1) with the content: "Your Mesage Goes Here"

3. we merge the cells in range A1:D1 (4 cells) using `myWorkSheet['!merges'] = [{ s: 'A1', e: 'D1' }];`

   The rest is self explanatory I think

## Here's a working example

```js
myObject = [
  { name: "Moran", role: "back" },
  { name: "Alain", role: "front" },
  { name: "Tony", role: "back" },
  { name: "Mike", role: "back" },
  { name: "Abo", role: "back" },
  { name: "Toni", role: "back" }
];

function exportWS() {
  var myFile = "myFile.xlsx";
  var myWorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myObject);
  var myWorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(myWorkBook, myWorkSheet, "myWorkSheet");
  XLSX.writeFile(myWorkBook, myFile);
}
function exportWSPlus() {
  var myFile = "myFilePlus.xlsx";
  var myWorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myObject);
  XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(myWorkSheet, [["Your Mesage Goes Here"]], { origin: 0 });
  var merges = myWorkSheet['!merges'] = [{ s: 'A1', e: 'D1' }];
  var myWorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(myWorkBook, myWorkSheet, "myWorkSheet");
  XLSX.writeFile(myWorkBook, myFile);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="exportWS()">Export Worksheet</button>
<button type="button" onclick="exportWSPlus()">Export Worksheet+</button>
```

feel free to ask any questions you may have.

Comment: I checked your code. Somehow your code has solved my one problem for message but now column headers are missing. any idea about it ?

Comment: I see that json to sheet conversion assigns row 1 for column headers, that's why message has overwrite them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped me in solving the issue partially.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't available to assist you further,  you basically create a sheet > write you message and merge cells > add json data to the sheet.

Comment: Great!+1 it works at first attempt ;-). One question plz..Can we convert json to PDF,CSV using above library? if yes please give sample code..Thanks in advance